# Laravel eloquent belongs to many query returns entries multiple time

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, eloquent

I have a `products`, `users` and `products_marks` table. Users can "mark" products. When they mark one product the database stores the `user_id` and the `product_id` in the `products_marks` table.

Marks basically mean a user wants to watch this product and has a watchlist. Of course I want to show the user all products he has marked. This means I have to get all products where the `user_id` in the `products_marks` table matches the actually user. However, I have some extra requirements to this as well.

Products do have a `post_status_id`. This represents weather the product is publish, offline, in review, pending, etc. The marked products should only be represented to the user if the product is also online. **BUT** if the user has marked a product which he has posted by himself, so he is the owner of the product, he should also see this product when it is publish **AND** pending.

This also works in most cases. I already have an eloquent query for this. But now I have found a strange problem. A user reported me that he sees one product two times in his watchlist. I have run the SQL query for exactly this user and yes, the database is returning the product two times! Why this? What do I have to change in order to get each product only once?

User model:

```
/** Relationship */
public function markedProducts(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Product', 'products_marks');
}

/** Eloquent Query */
public static function markedProductsPaginated(User $user){
    $products = Product::select('products.*')
        ->join('products_marks', 'products_marks.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
        ->whereHas('marks', function ($query) use ($user) {
            $query->where(function($query) use ($user){
                $query->where('products_marks.user_id', $user->id);
            });
            $query->where(function($query){
                $query->where('page_status_id', PageStatus::getIdByStatus('publish'));
            });
            $query->orWhere(function($query) use ($user){
                $query->where('page_status_id', PageStatus::getIdByStatus('pending'))
                    ->where('products.user_id', $user->id);
            });
        })
        ->orderBy('products_marks.created_at', 'desc')
        ->paginate(10);

    $products->loadCount('allPublishedComments');

    return $products;
}
```

Query as SQL statement:

```
select `products`.* from `products` inner join `products_marks` on `products_marks`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` where exists (select * from `users` inner join `products_marks` on `users`.`id` = `products_marks`.`user_id` where `products`.`id` = `products_marks`.`product_id` and ((`products_marks`.`user_id` = 19) and (`page_status_id` = 1) or (`page_status_id` = 4 and `products`.`user_id` = 3))) order by `products_marks`.`created_at` desc limit 10 offset 0
```

I have also created a [db fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3d89bdb4a4608023d6d63cfd0b727c45) where you can run this SQL statement and see that the database is returning the entry for the user_id `13` two times. But why is that? And why only sometimes?

It looks like when multiple users mark the same product I get it multiple times back. As you can see in the fiddle the product with the id `43` got marked two times!

Kind regards and thank you!

Comment: `->join()` makes duplicates in a 1toN obviously, so idk what do you expect

Comment: Well, I want to get all products where user_id = `13` and either the product is publish (1) or the user (13) is the owner of the product. If so, the product can also be pending (4). But I don't want to get one entry multiple times

Comment: those functions you posted are inside the User Model?

Comment: Yes. Because I want all marked products for that specif user @Berto99

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```
/** Eloquent Query */
public static function markedProductsPaginated(User $user){
    $products = $user->products()->withPivot('created_at')->select('products.*')
        ->whereHas('marks', function ($query) use ($user) {
            $query->where(function($query){
                $query->where('page_status_id', PageStatus::getIdByStatus('publish'));
            });
            $query->orWhere(function($query) use ($user){
                $query->where('page_status_id', PageStatus::getIdByStatus('pending'))
                    ->where('products.user_id', $user->id);
            });
        })
        ->orderBy('products_marks.created_at', 'desc')
        ->paginate(10);

    $products->loadCount('allPublishedComments');

    return $products;
}
```

Comment: This returns be the following error (orderBy doesn't know the created_at) SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products_marks.created_at' in 'order clause' (SQL: select `products`.* from `products` where `products`.`user_id` = 1 and `products`.`user_id` is not null and exists (select * from `users` inner join `products_marks` on `users`.`id` = `products_marks`.`user_id` where `products`.`id` = `products_marks`.`product_id` and ((`page_status_id` = 1) or (`page_status_id` = 4 and `products`.`user_id` = 1))) order by `products_marks`.`created_at` desc limit 10 offset 0)

Comment: Any idea how to solve this? This is the reason why I went with `join`

Comment: @Jan try now, i've added `->withPivot('created_at')`, otherwise please post the SQL generated by laravel (there should be a `->toSql()` method )